# XML parser to VIewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, android-viewpager

I am trying to work on an application that parse an `XML` file to my Application. Basically, my little app is trying to load images from `XML` file unto a `ViewPagerAdapter`. So please I need help either on tutorials or sample codes to work on. the `XML` file looks like this;

```
<Items

  <Item>
    <src>http://mysite/data/cool-pictures/Cool-pictures-1.jpg</src>
    <Name>Picture 1</Name>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Src>http://mysite/data/cool-pictures/Cool-pictures-10.jpg</Src>
    <Name>Picture 2</Name>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Src>http://mysite/data/cool-pictures/Cool-pictures-11.jpg</Src>
    <Name>Picture 3</Name>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Src>http://mysite/data/cool-pictures/Cool-pictures-12.jpg</Src>
    <Name>Picture 4</Name>
  </Item>

</Items>
```

Please how can I go about it.
Moreso, here is the code for the adapter class.

```
public class ViewpagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] carName;
    int[] carImage;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewpagerAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] carName, int[] carImage) {
    this.context = mainActivity;
    this.carName=carName;
    this.carImage = carImage;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return carImage.length;
}

 @Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
   container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    TextView carText;
    ImageView carView;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container,false);
    carText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_text);
    carView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.car_image);

    carText.setText(carName[position]);
    carView.setImageResource(carImage[position]);

    container.addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last I've got an answer to the problem. What I did was to have a class to handle my XML. and the code is given below.

```
 public List<ItemModel> parse(InputStream is){
    XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
    try {
        pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(is, null);
        parseXMl(parser);
    }catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print("-----Parse" + myItems);
    return myItems;
}

private void parseXMl(XmlPullParser parser) {
    int event;
    try {
        event = parser.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String name = parser.getName();
            switch (event){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Item")){
                        myItem = new ItemModel();
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (name.equals("Item")){
                        myItems.add(myItem);
                    }else if (name.equals("Name")){
                        myItem.setName(text);
                    }else if (name.equals("Src")){
                        myItem.setSource(text);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            event = parser.next();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Then on my `MainActivity` class, I called the XMlHandler.

```
XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();
List<YourItems> myItems = handler.parse(getAssets().open("items.xml"));
```

Note that if you I created an asset folder and dump my `XML` file there. That was why I was able to use `getAssets()`. 
So I passed `myItems` into an `adapter` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

This will help you to get the answer for your question.

Comment: Hello, it look kinda difficult any simple one?

Comment: what's the difficult in that tutorial?